# Cannot retrieve recently added values with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two view controllers in my app: the first one *displays* items pulled from a Firebase database, and the second one lets users *add and remove items* from the database.

The problem is when a user adds an item in the second view controller and goes back to the first controller really fast. This will sometimes cause the Firebase database not save the item. As a consequence the first view controller won't to display the newly added items.

As far as the implantation goes, I fetch items in `viewWillAppear` and then remove the Firebase listener observer in `viewDidDisappear`. How can I fix this?

```
// first view controller code

var items = [Item]()

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

func fetchItems() {
    ref.child("items").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.items = []
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            if let dictionary = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                // Create item and append it to an items array
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)                
    self.fetchItems()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for View Controller 2?

Comment: Firebase work asynchronously, so instead of calling data in viewWillAppear use a delegate in viewController2 for tableView of viewController1 to reload data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use observeSingleEvent since you want the code to be executed every time the firebase database changes. So, change it:

```
func fetchItems() {
ref.child("items").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    self.items = []
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        if let dictionary = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            // Create item and append it to an items array
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

}

This will create a listener. Also, since you didn't create an observer before, you didn't have to use `removeAllObservers()`. Now that you have one it's correct to use it.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this code is that when the user swipes to delete a cell in the first view controller, the listener will be triggered and `self.tableView.reloadData()` won't give time for the swipe-to-delete table view animation to finish.

Comment: Can I see the code of that part? Are you using the editActionsForRowAt indexPath? What kind of animation should perform?

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up Jaime. I am using `deleteSectionsAt` in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method.

Comment: Ok I've been thinking about it. I've never used that function but try this: When you call the `deleteSectionsAt`, before removing any value in Firebase, call `removeAllObservers()`. With that the observer won't be triggered and you will finish your animation. After finishing it call `fetchItems()`. That will update your data and restore the observer, so you'll have it again. Hope you don't have problems this time :)

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I'll try this method very soon! My main concern is that when the user deletes items really fast and tableview.reloadData() may get in the way and mess with some animations.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, your solution fixed my issue!